# Integrating Onetrust cookie consent banner with Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, one-trust

I want to integrate a cookie banner from Onetrust.

When I am implementing a Onetrust cookie consent banner, I followed all the steps that it requires

1. I scan my website on Onetrust dashboard so it can scan all cookies that appears on my website.
2. I categorize all cookies with the following categories (Stricly neccessary, functionnal, targeting, performance)
3. I deploy my script and copy pasted the code inside the top of the head section, and I select the Autoblocking technologies of Onetrust, so it can autoblock all of my website cookies.

My cookies are indeed blocked, however I get the following error
**Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js**

The thing is this works fine when I deploy my application without the cookie consent banner.

When the banner is deployed, I get this error until I accept all cookies and then refresh the application -> It will work perfectly fine after. But I need my users to use the app without accepting the cookies ( or even without the need to refresh after accepting the cookies).

So my concern here is, is it even possible to use Onetrust technologies on a Angular application, and If it is, is their any fix to resolve ZoneJS issue ?

I looked inside my cookies ( f12 -> applications -> cookies ) and none of the cookie seems related to ZoneJS. I do believe that zonejs is injected by the angular app as a script tag, but I might be wrong about that.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://www.npmjs.com/package/@altack/ngx-onetrust